# Sum rules for parton distribution functions

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

In Schwarz, the parton distribution functions for proton has the following sum rules,
$$
\int dx f_u(x)=2\quad,\quad\int dxf_d(x)=1
$$
where $x$ is the fraction of momenta of proton carried by the parton species or Bjroken *x*. Then we can write
$$
\sum_i\int dx f_i(x)=3 \quad \text{for any hadron includes 3 partons}
$$
Then he gives the result
$$
\sum_i\int xf_i(x)dx=1 \tag{1}
$$
Now to prove 1 we can take the definition of x as fraction, hence we can use $\sum_i\langle x\rangle_i=1$, the average value of $x$. Then we use
$$
\frac{\sum_i\int xf_i(x)dx}{\sum_i\int f_i(x)dx}=1
$$
which means
$$
\sum_i\int xf_i(x)dx=3
$$
Where I am doing mistake.

References : Schwarz pp 676